# Python Pandas - 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str' - .str.replace error

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace

I am trying to replace "," by "" for 80 columns in a panda dataframe.
I have create a list of this headers to iterate:

```
headers = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3'... 'h80']
```

and then I am using a list of headers to replace multiple columns string value as bellow:

```
dataFrame[headers] = dataFrame[headers].str.replace(',','')
```

Which gave me this error : AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
When I try the same on only one header it works well, and I need to use the "str.replace" because the only "replace" method does sadly not replace the ",".

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Using df.apply

`pd.Series.str.replace` is a series method not for data frames. You can use `apply` on each row/column series instead.

```
dataFrame[headers] = dataFrame[headers].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',',''))
```

#### Using df.applymap

Or, you can use `applymap` and treat each cell as a string and use replace directly on them -

```
dataFrame[headers] = dataFrame[headers].applymap(lambda x: x.replace(',',''))
```

#### Using df.replace

You can also use df.replace which is a method available to replace values in df directly across all columns selected. But, for this purpose you will have to set `regex=True`

```
dataFrame[headers] = dataFrame[headers].replace(',','',regex=True)
```